# Element "this" in Chrome extension popup does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, scroll, this

I'm developing the popup window of my Chrome extension. I bind a callback in scroll event of a `div` with selector like this:

```
$('#activity-tab .activity-list').bind('scroll', () => {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight){
// My code goes here
}
);
```

But it interprets `this` as the `Window` in popup, not the element with selector itself. I have to change my code into this to make it work properly:

But

```
$('#activity-tab .activity-list').bind('scroll', () => {
                    let element = $('#activity-tab .activity-list');
                    if (element.scrollTop() + element.innerHeight() >= element[0].scrollHeight){
// My code goes here
}
);
```

Why doesn't `this` work properly in Chrome popup environment?

Comment: Nothing to do with "Chrome popup environment" - learn the difference between `function` and `arrow function` ... they are not always interchangeable ... in this case they are not, as `this` works differently in arrow functions

Comment: Because you used an arrow function, which doesn’t have its own `this`.